# Swift tvOS App Main Thread blocked for a few seconds then resuming

Tags: swift, xcode, instruments, tvos, apple-tv

I have an iOS game app I've created a tvOS version of. It's solely UIKit and animates on a **CADisplayLink** running about 30fps. The app works fine on iPhone and iPad but on the Apple TV it runs ok but then freezes for a few seconds before resuming. It appears that the program is just stopped.

Initially I stripped everything out of the **CADisplayLink** and reintroduced calls one by one to no avail to see if anything was causing the problem but whatever I took out the issue was still there.

I've ran it through instruments, System Trace, Time Profiler and Core Animation instruments. It appears to call `mach_msg_trap` on the main thread, and still appears to be running, but looking at Time Profiler no code in the display link is being run. The best example I can show is the Core Animation Instrument.

[image: Core Animation Instrument ScreenShot]

We can see the FPS running along at about 40, and the cpu bouncing up and down around 20-30% but then for a time the fps is 0 and so is device utilisation, during these periods the CPU Usage goes up slightly and seems consistent throughout the period the app is frozen (around 40%).

This is running on a 4th Gen Apple TV running tvOS 12.2. But the same behaviour is seen running on the simulator for Apple TV and Apple TV 4k

It looks like something external to the app is blocking the Main Thread, the only main differences between this and the iOS app is that I've added control for the gamepad / remote as opposed to touch events, but I've even removed that to see if it was the issue and it's not.

Also I have sound FX playing on a different thread, and these stop too, so it's not just the main thread that is paused.

Comment: Are you able to pause the app in the debugger when it seems frozen so that you can inspect what is actually on each thread/queue?

Comment: Hi Philip, its running something but generally I hit libsystem_platform.dylib`os_unfair_lock_lock_with_options: or os_unfair_lock_unlock on the main thread every time I pause whilst its in the stuck state.

Comment: Also when it's running cpu is about 50-70% but goes up to 100% when stuck.